# Javascript: element.click() in a loop

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript.

Currently, I want to download a few images from the website with Javascript, this is my tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.indnt1').find('a').each(function() {
     if($(this).attr('target') === "_blank") {
          var image = this;
          console.log(image);
          image.click();
      }
   });
});
```

HTML structure:

```
<ul class="indnt1">
    <li>
        <a href="ht.tp://mysite.com/2021%20.jpg"
            target="_blank">pic1.jpg</a>
        <span class="textPanelFooter">(
            271 KB
            )</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="ht.tp://mysite.com/2022%20.jpg"
            target="_blank">pic2.jpg</a>
        <span class="textPanelFooter">(
            349 KB
            )</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="ht.tp://mysite.com/2024%20.jpg"
            target="_blank">pic4.jpg</a>
        <span class="textPanelFooter">(
            319 KB
            )</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="ht.tp://mysite.com/2023%20.jpg"
            target="_blank">pic3.jpg</a>
        <span class="textPanelFooter">(
            218 KB
            )</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Basically, This script is going to find the  and download the image from it. But I don't know why my script is just able to download the first image, it cannot download multiple images as I expected.

Could someone help me out? And why it not work?
Thank you.

Comment: please add your html structure to question too

Comment: try using while condition instead of if condition.

Comment: Use `$(image).click();`. Note that the trigger only works if you have already written an jquery eventhandler for the anchor tag

Comment: Hi folks, I just updated the HTML structure to question. @HienNguyen

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting the save as dialogue box to appear? Or to have the images automatically downloaded to a location?

Anyway, I tried this and I see the network traffic downloading images.

```
$('img').each(function(a, ing) {
    var src = img.src;
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.src = src;
    iframe.id = "frame";
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
});
```

Maybe this points you in the right direction.
Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Hi bro,
I just updated the HTML structure, I want to the images automatically downloaded to a location. I tried out your code but it did not work for me. I'm just back to searching...

Comment: "JavaScript doesn't have a file handling support unlike most languages.

This is due to security reasons and how quickly JavaScript was built in a short time with a lot of restrictions from Netscape." Taken from: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-code-in-JavaScript-to-download-my-files-to-a-specific-folder-where-I-want-to-save

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
 var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var srcList = [];
    var i = 0;

    setInterval(function(){
        if(images.length > i){
            srcList.push(images[i].src);
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            link.id=i;
            link.download = images[i].src;
            link.href = images[i].src;
            link.click();
            i++;
        }
    },1500);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click image, an popup block show, you should allow popup option in browser.

I tried your code in local, it worked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.indnt1').find('a').each(function() {
     if($(this).attr('target') === "_blank") {
          var image = this;
          console.log(image);
          image.click();
      }
   });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="indnt1">
    <li>
        <a href="http://placehold.it/100x100"
            target="_blank">pic1</a>
        <span class="textPanelFooter">(
            271 KB
            )</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://placehold.it/100x100"
            target="_blank">pic2</a>
        <span class="textPanelFooter">(
            349 KB
            )</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://placehold.it/100x100"
            target="_blank">pic3</a>
        <span class="textPanelFooter">(
            319 KB
            )</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://placehold.it/100x100"
            target="_blank">pic4</a>
        <span class="textPanelFooter">(
            218 KB
            )</span>
    </li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know why it just works for the first one. I mean it can download the first image. For the other images, the script cannot continue downloading, even though the code is still running without any error appears. My expectation is able to download all 4 images.
Also, Thanks for your attention.